# Confusion on the tensor product $I\otimes_A A/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Sorry for this trivial question. But I am confusing myself with it.
Given an ideal $I$ of a ring $A$.Now $I$ can be regarded as an $A$-module with map
$$A\times I\to A\\ (a,i)\mapsto a\cdot i$$
I belive that by module theory, one should have an $A$-module isomorphism
$$I\otimes_A A/I\cong I/I^2$$
However, since the tensor $I\otimes_A A/I$ is generated by elements $i\otimes \bar{1}$ for all $i\in I$. Don't we have the following equalities?
$$i\otimes\bar{1}=(i\cdot 1)\otimes \bar{1}=i(1\otimes\bar{1})=1\otimes (i\cdot \bar{1})=1\otimes \bar{i}=0$$
which means the tensor should be zero.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It's a good question. I also made this mistake when starting to learn tensor products!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you. I skimmed through these algebra for algebraic geometry. Now I am paying for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the second equality. $1$ is not an element of $I$ (unless $I = A$), so $1 \otimes \bar{1}$ is not an element of $I \otimes_A A/I$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for the concise and quick answer! I will accpet the answer after a few minutes allowed.